# Is Ultimate Tic Tac Toe solved?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, tic-tac-toe, ultimate-tic-tac-toe

[Ultimate Tic Tac Toe](http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/06/16/ultimate-tic-tac-toe/) is an interesting variant of Tic Tac Toe where in each of the 9 fields, a “regular” game of Tic Tac Toe is played; see the link for details.

Has this game been solved already? Would it be possible to solve it using a brute force mini-max strategy?

Comment: There has been a discussion on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5898506), but nothing definite yet.

Comment: Great question!  I did some searching and found [this link from 2014 (redditt)](https://www.reddit.com/r/geek/comments/2ki98o/ultimate_tic_tac_toe/) that claims it has been solved.  Still trying to run down some corroboration, and will post if I find.

Answer (score 7):

My co-worker found what I believe is [a winning strategy for the first player](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/604-Ultimate-Tic-Tac-Toe-is-always-won-by-X.html), but now I find [earlier evidence by others](https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/in-tic-tac-toe-ception-perfect/1681243068) as well.

This is for the original version of the game, where you can send your opponent to an already won field and he has to place his mark there. It seems that the question is still open for the updated version where he can then choose freely.

Comment: It looks like you've missed the clarification in the rules: "What if my opponent sends me to a board that’s already been won? In that case, congratulations – you get to go anywhere you like, on any of the other boards. (This means you should avoid sending your opponent to an already-won board!)"

Comment: (I've just seen that you've actually already fielded this point in the comments on your blog :-)